# How can we use 3 different databases in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

How can we establish multiple databases connection in Laravel. I have to save  data in 3 different tables in laravel. I have to connect one laravel application with 3 databases. Is it any way to do this?

Comment: Databases and tables are not the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please go through this link [how to set multiple databases in laravel](http://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections)

Comment: Thanks this one was helpful